# Connect Spring Boot Application to a MongoDB Container on Docker

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker

I have created a simple spring boot application that needs to connect to a mongo db database hosted on a docker container. But no matter what permutation or combination I try with the configuration it does not seem to work and stop and some point, here is the config I have done so far

**application.properties**

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=docker-mongo-service **(I have tried 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1, and localhost, only the JAR file is created, but the container shows an error in connecting to the mongo container)**
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=users
server.port=8080
```

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27018
spring.data.mongodb.database=users
server.port=8080
```

this version is only able to talk to the database if I run the app from IntelliJ IDEA or postman, but cannot connect to the database when it is run on Docker.

**error for localhost:27018**

```
INFO 1 --- [localhost:27018] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27018
2023-03-07T10:49:19.475466464Z 
2023-03-07T10:49:19.475472102Z com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
2023-03-07T10:49:19.475476001Z  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:73) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar!/:na]
2023-03-07T10:49:19.475480478Z  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:183) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar!/:na]
2023-03-07T10:49:19.475484289Z  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:198) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar!/:na]
2023-03-07T10:49:19.475488368Z  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:158) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar!/:na]
2023-03-07T10:49:19.475500487Z  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
2023-03-07T10:49:19.475504485Z Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
2023-03-07T10:49:19.475508415Z  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
2023-03-07T10:49:19.475512151Z  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
2023-03-07T10:49:19.475515746Z  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:539) ~[na:na]
2023-03-07T10:49:19.475519708Z  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:594) ~[na:na]
2023-03-07T10:49:19.475523952Z  at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
2023-03-07T10:49:19.475528048Z  at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
2023-03-07T10:49:19.475531926Z  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:107) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar!/:na]
2023-03-07T10:49:19.475535871Z  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:82) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar!/:na]
2023-03-07T10:49:19.475539944Z  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:68) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar!/:na]
2023-03-07T10:49:19.475544141Z  ... 4 common frames omitted
```

**mongodb container** (it is exposed on localhost:27018 since I already have mongo running locally on 27017)

```
Port 27017    0.0.0.0:27018
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:latest

COPY target/*.jar app.jar

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

**error for docker-mongo-service:27017**

```
INFO 4920 --- [o-service:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server docker-mongo-service:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: docker-mongo-service
    at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:217) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:78) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:68) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:183) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:198) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:158) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: docker-mongo-service
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:801) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:887) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1367) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1301) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:209) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar:na]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
```

I have tried changing the host to

- 127.0.0.1
- 0.0.0.0
- localhost
- docker-mongo-service (name of the container of mongo image)

P.S: I can't use Docker-Compose with it.

Comment: I do not have experience with connecting a Spring boot application to a mongodb but i do have experience with connecting an Express.js application to a mongodb container I use `docker-compose` and there i set environment variables with the value of the url set as the name of the container, this way it does work for me. If you want to do it without `docker-compose` you can use the `--network host` on both containers to just run them on your localhost network and just connect with localhost:27017

Comment: Both the containers are running on localhost, and I can actually connect to the MongoDB database via the Compass app, but the Spring App does not run.

Comment: are you sure that they are running on localhost and not in their own container and just exposing a single port to the localhost of your computer?

Comment: or you can use a `docker service` to connect the two containers, this is actually the recommended way to do it to keep your container seperated from the system